# What happens between sending parameters and storing them in DB? (Ruby on Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I am trying to create an application using Ruby on Rails 4 (still a newbie). However it seems like I can't store the exact long numbers (latitude/longitude coordinates) a user creates. But if he updates an already existing record, the correct values will be inserted. I only have a problem with the creation process.

For instance, when creating an item with these coordinates: **47.96039291127528** lat and **47.96039291127528** long, this is what gets sent as parameters:

```
Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-22 11:58:09 +0200
Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Yfu5QR4e9x3vPtdTF9uVF9CTYebXKyaqbjTGo7KQdDI=", "item"=>{"latitude"=>"47.96039291127528", "longitude"=>"47.96039291127528"}, "commit"=>"Save Item"}
```

So the parameters that get sent are correct. But these are the following lines in the console describing what gets inserted in DB:

```
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `items` (`created_at`, `gmaps`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-11-22 09:58:09', 1, 47.4560127, 48.9459587, '2013-11-22 09:58:09')
```

So these are completely wrong. I use Gmaps4rails, which just removes the last few digits from a coordinate, it does NOT approximate it, when displaying the map.

What I tried, with no result:

- Using sqlite3 instead of mysql2
- Creating a very simple new rails project just for testing, without me processing the numbers - just trying to store them.
- Changing the lat/long data type to anything: **text, string, decimal etc**. Currently I use text as type.

So, my question is: what happens between sending the parameters and inserting these in the DB? And how can I check that? Does Active Record do anything with the parameters regarding approximation? If yes, why, as long as I use text as data type?

Thank You!

---

Item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_gmappable

  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{latitude}, #{longitude}"
  end

end
```

ItemsController#create

```
  def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item].permit(:latitude, :longitude))
    if @item.save
      redirect_to @item
    else
      render 'new'
    end   end
```

Comment: what data type are you using for storing altitude and longitude in your db? Can it store that large number?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, I tried various options: decimal, string, text.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think you need to use :precision and :scale values for decimal,see this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html

Comment: you should use v2 of gmaps4rails, then use geocoder

Comment: What is the ItemsController#create code? Item model code?

Comment: @user2675613 used them, with no help.
- apneadiving thanks, I'll do the update later, but normally it should work, I guess. Probably the problem is on my side.
- dimuch edited the question with the code